# finding the special point of triangle when perpendicular lengths from a point is given and a condition of minimum.

Tags: geometry, triangles, area, maxima-minima

$P$ is a point inside a triangle $ABC$ of area $K$ ($K>0$) .The lengths of perpendiculars drawn to the sides
$BC$, $CA$, $AB$ of lengths $a,b,c$ are respectively $P_1$, $P_2$, $P_3$. If
$\frac{a}{P_1} + \frac{b}{P_2} +\frac{c}{P_3}$ is minimum, then $P$ is which special point of triangle? Also find $P_1,P_2,P_3$.

> I thought of using Viviani's theorem but realized that it was for equilateral triangle. I am struggling, how to relate area of triangle with given quantities? Also the condition given does not seems direct.

Comment: Hint: $\frac12(aP_1 + bP_2 + cP_3) = ???$

Comment: ok that is the area.but still i am not able to handle that minimum condition part.

Comment: Hint2: $\frac{a}{P_1} + \frac{b}{P_2} + \frac{c}{P_3} = \frac{a^2}{aP_1} + \frac{b^2}{bP_2} + \frac{c^2}{cP_3}$ and apply Engel's form of Cauchy Schwarz inequality (also known as [Titu's lemma](https://brilliant.org/wiki/titus-lemma/)). Look up the condition when the inequality becomes equality....